# best way to to get faster record searching in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a more than *Billion records in mysql database* , the problem is when I execute a select query it takes more than **3 minutes** to search for that string.

So which is the best way to store and retrieve when I have large amount of data? 
My table has 4 columns:

```
 Serial_no,  product_name,  product_id,  location
```

The serial number is auto increment from  1.
And I have duplicate `product_id` exits. I didn't performed any indexing, just created a table and querying using

```
select * from table where condition
```

So What Should I do If I want to have a faster query searching?

**edit :** I am using the below query :

```
select * from the table where product_name="Example";
```

Should I change my db to other db?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using and sample data.  No doubt, indexing is the solution to your problem.

Comment: depend  on which type of seacrh you need .. update your question and tell us the search you really need  .. show us the code you are using

Comment: i want to see the the details of product using product name !

Comment: no indices => no database ,use Excel ;) Index all fields in joins, where, order by and group by, unless you are inserting or updating many rows (which is slower with indices).

Comment: [CREATE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would create the index according which is my most used fields in the where in my queries, in this case maybe your main field could be product_id so it should be the cluster index and create a non cluster index with the product_name

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [itable_productname] ON table 
(
    product_name ASC
)
```